# Given a 2D matrix of size MxN with positive integer values, find the closed loop that has the maximum sum

Tags: algorithm, matrix, optimization

A loop can be of arbitrary shape but can only go up/down/left/right. The sum of a loop is defined as the sum of  all the unique elements along its perimeter. The loop is not allowed to cross itself as that would be suboptimal (since we are not allowed to count the same element twice).

Does anyone know of any approach that can be used to solve this in polynomial time? Someone asked me this but I don't have any clue how to do it with a DP or otherwise.

EDIT - The loop should be convex as well.

Comment: I think you're missing a condition/ limitation somewhere on the question. You could easily construct a curve that doesn't cross itself but covers every element in the matrix, which would be optimal (see space filling curves)

Comment: You are correct, I guess I am looking for a convex loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the outline of a DP solution.

For every pair of points find the max convex arc that if it bows, bows away from the bottom left.

For every pair of points find the max convex arc that if it bows, bows away from the top right.

Find the pair of points where the sum of those two arcs is maximal.  That pair of arcs is your answer.